# Error en uso de constructores

Tags: c++, clase, constructor

Tengo una clase llamada `class Jugador` y tiene algunos atributos, cuando ejecuto el main, ejecuta bien con este codigo.

```
#include <iostream>

class Jugador{
    private:
        string name;
        Pokemon pokemon_1;
        Pokemon pokemon_2;
        Pokemon pokemon_3;
        Pokemon pokemon_4;
        Pokemon pokemon_5;
    public:
        
};
```

Pero solo quiero agregarle un constructor por defecto, básico, y me manda error.

```
#include <iostream>


class Jugador{
    private:
        string name;
        Pokemon pokemon_1;
        Pokemon pokemon_2;
        Pokemon pokemon_3;
        Pokemon pokemon_4;
        Pokemon pokemon_5;
    public:
        Jugador(){
        }
};
```

Y también lo definí fuera.

Este es el error:
**include\Jugador.h|14|error: no matching function for call to 'Pokemon::Pokemon()'|**

Comment: ¿Ya definiste el constructor por fuera de la clase?

Comment: Si,tambien lo definí fuera

Comment: Ok, lo que no entiendo es por que le pones los corchetes dentro de la clase. Osea, en la clase sería: `Jugador();` y afuera: `Jugador::Jugador() {}`.

Comment: Si, hice eso, pero no funciona, creo que el problema está cuando instancio los objetos Pokemon en mi clase Jugador, pero no sé como solucionarlo.

Comment: ¿Tiene constructor la clase Pokemon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si te fijas, el error no hace referencia al constructor de la clase `Jugador` si no al constructor de la clase `Pokemon`:

> ```
> error: no matching function for call to 'Pokemon::Pokemon()
> ```

Para que un objeto pueda tener un constructor por defecto (un constructor que no recibe parámetros), todos sus sub-objetos deben ser construibles por defecto, podemos reproducir tu error de esta manera:

```
struct No_soy_construible_por_defecto
{
    No_soy_construible_por_defecto(std::string); // Constructor con string.
};

struct Jugador
{
    Jugador() {}
    No_soy_construible_por_defecto pokemon;
//  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <-- Error, no se puede construir porque no le pasamos
//                                     ningún std::string.
};
```

Para solucionar el problema, tienes las siguientes opciones:

1. Añade un constructor por defecto al sub-objeto:

   ```
    struct Soy_construible_por_defecto
    {
        Soy_construible_por_defecto(std::string); // Constructor con string.
        Soy_construible_por_defecto();            // Constructor por defecto.
    };

    struct Jugador
    {
        Jugador() {}
        Soy_construible_por_defecto pokemon;
    };
   ```
2. Construye los sub-objetos en el constructor por defecto de `Jugador`:

   ```
    class Jugador{
        private:
            string name;
            No_soy_construible_por_defecto pokemon_1;
            No_soy_construible_por_defecto pokemon_2;
            No_soy_construible_por_defecto pokemon_3;
            No_soy_construible_por_defecto pokemon_4;
            No_soy_construible_por_defecto pokemon_5;
        public:
            Jugador() :
                pokemon_1("Tangela"),
                pokemon_2("Dunsparce"),
                pokemon_3("Tropius"),
                pokemon_4("Pachirisu"),
                pokemon_5("Agumon")
            {}
    };
   ```